# Objective c post with json data request to server

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to post data to server and send data json like this

`data:  {"userID":"AAAAA","token":"12345","type":"BBB","version":"45"}`

[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCltD.png)

```
 NSDictionary *requestDictionary = @{@"data" : @{
                                       @"{userID" : @"AAA", @"token ": @"12345",@"type":@"iOS",@"version":@"1}"}};

NSURL *urls =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/send_code"]];

self.request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[self.request setURL:urls];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"application/json"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"IOS" forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-Application-Platform"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDictionary options:0 error:nil]];
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDictionary options:0 error:nil];

urlconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:true];
```

i ve tried several times and get invalid data response

please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: Please, add what response you expect, what you get and why this is not the expected response.

Comment: You set a header which tells the server the request is form-url-encoded, but you send it as JSON.  If I were your server, I'd be confused too.

Comment: i send it as json data is key and the value is JSON

Comment: Are you sure that `requestDictionary` is valid? The "{" and "}" inside the key and the last value is quite weird (especially since `NSDictionary` doesn't assure at all an order since it's Key access and not index access).

Comment: you need to send the dictionary not array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send using AFNetworking:

First try to convert Json into Dictionary.

```
NSError *error;
NSData *objectData = [@"{Your dictionary}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:&error];
```

Then you can send this dictionary:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:@"your_URL" parameters:json progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Complete");
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail");
}];
```

Comment: thanks this is work for me , how to handle reply in AFNetworking?

Comment: if this is works for you then you can accept my answer bro...@YonathanKoutenshidatshu..:)

Comment: and how to handle reply means?... what do you want exactly... i didn't understand.... pls tell me in brief..@YonathanKoutenshidatshu

Comment: in my situation manager post json successfully, and give log complete. 
then i post my URL to the server, server give response json to my device, and my question how to handle response reply from sever using AFNetworking?

Comment: _str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  like this way... In _str (string) you can store your response.. and then use it when you want..:)